# How can I define insert function for Set when Set is optional in Swift?

Tags: swift

My goal is to be able insert new item to an optional set which this set has nil value before. For that reason i created this extension, but it does not work, and still I cannot insert a new item to a nil set.

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == Set<String> {
    func myInsert(_ value: String) -> Self {
        if let unwrappedSet: Set<String> = self {
            var newSet: Set<String> = unwrappedSet
            newSet.insert(value)
            return newSet
        }
        else {
            let set: Set<String>? = [value]
            return set
        }
    }
}
```

use case:

```
func myTest() -> Set<String>? {
    var set: Set<String>? = nil
    set.myInsert("Hello")
    return set
}

if let set: Set<String> = myTest() {
    print(set)
}
```

---

I refuse to believe there is issue with my extension, and i think the issue is from xcode itself, look the function below it is same function but outside of extension, it does works!

```
func myInsert(set: Set<String>?, value: String) -> Set<String>? {
    if let unwrappedSet: Set<String> = set {
        var newSet: Set<String> = unwrappedSet
        newSet.insert(value)
        return newSet
    }
    else {
        let set: Set<String>? = [value]
        return set
    }
}
```

use case:

```
let set: Set<String>? = nil
let newSet = myInsert(set: set, value: "Hello")
let newSet2 = myInsert(set: newSet, value: "World")
print(newSet2)
```

result:

> Optional(Set(["Hello", "World"]))

Comment: `set.myInsert("Hello")` don't you have a warning for unused return value?

Comment: Yes, that is why i said it does not work.

Comment: Why not change to this: return set.myInsert("Hello")  ?

Answer (score 2):

From your test case code:

```
var set: Set<String>? = nil
set.myInsert("Hello")
```

you expect the variable `set` to change from `nil` to a wrapped `Set<String>` containing the `String` `"Hello"`.  In order for the value to modify itself, the `func` must be `mutating`.

Make `myInsert` a `mutating` `func` and assign the new `set` to `self`.  Since `myInsert` is `mutating`, it doesn't need to return a value which your test is ignoring anyway:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == Set<String> {
    mutating func myInsert(_ value: String) {
        if self == nil {
            self = [value]
        } else {
            self?.insert(value)
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Test

```
func myTest() -> Set<String>? {
    var set: Set<String>? = nil
    set.myInsert("Hello")
    set.myInsert("Goodbye")
    return set
}

if let set = myTest() {
    print(set)
}
```

> ```
> ["Hello", "Goodbye"]
> ```

---

### Making `insert` more usable

(Thanks to @LeoDabus for his suggestions)

We can make this work with a `Set` of any type and make it more like the original `insert` on `Set` by having it return a `@discardableResult` containing a tuple with a `Bool` indicating if a the value was inserted and the `memberAfterInsert`:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped: SetAlgebra {
    @discardableResult
    mutating func insert(_ newMember: Wrapped.Element) -> (inserted: Bool, memberAfterInsert: Wrapped.Element) {
        if self == nil {
            self = .init()
        }
        return self!.insert(newMember)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we have a way without mutating?! As you can see I am not using mutating and I am returning the needed value to be returned.

Comment: You are wanting to change a value that is `nil` into a `Optional(Set([value])`.  You have to *mutate* the value in order to do that.  What do you have against `mutating`?

Comment: Do not get me wrong, your answer is working, I wonder why my function does not! My code should working without needing to use mutating.

Comment: @vacawama better to constrain `Wrapped` to `SetAlgebra`

Comment: BTW, even the regular `insert` on `Set` is `mutating`.

Comment: Something like: `extension Optional where Wrapped: SetAlgebra {` `mutating func myInsert(_ value: Wrapped.Element) {` `if self == nil {` `self = Wrapped([value])` `} else {` `self?.insert(value)` `}` `}` `}`

Comment: btw I would also return a tuple. Something like `extension Optional where Wrapped: SetAlgebra {` `@discardableResult` `mutating func myInsert(_ value: Wrapped.Element) -> (inserted: Bool, memberAfterInsert: Wrapped.Element) {` `if self == nil { `self = Wrapped([value])` `return (true, value)` `} else {` `return self!.insert(value)` `}` `}` `}`

Comment: Your function isn't working because it is returning a value, but NOT *mutating* the original.  Your test clearly expects the original value to be changed, hence the need for *mutating*.

Comment: @LeoDabus, please check my update.

Comment: @vacawama kkkk thats exactly what I've just posted. Slightly different syntax.

Comment: I will remove my post

Comment: @vacawama: you mentioned about mutating things even with apple api for insert, but I am not overridden what apple done there, that mutating from apple is happening on my variable and I am returning the new created variable, look this code, this works without mutating, my approach in question must works as yours. `extension Optional where Wrapped == Set<String> {
    func myInsert2000() -> String { return "Hello World" }
}`

Comment: use case:                 `let set: Set<String>? = ["3"]
                let newValue = set.myInsert2000()
                print(newValue)`

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus.  I appreciate your input, and SO appreciates your input.

Comment: @ioscoder, your new example changes the test because you are assigning the result of the insert to a variable.  Of course you wouldn't need *mutating* in that case.

Comment: I upvoting your answer thanks to you and leo, but still having issue why I would need mutating even, since I am building a new value and returning the exact type that function returns, I can strongly say, this is a bug or issue from xcode, not from my code.

Comment: @ioscoder, there is nothing wrong with Xcode and there is nothing wrong with Swift. Look at your first use case. You are not using the value returned from myInsert. Had you written `set = set.myInsert(“Hello”)` then your code would have worked.  But you didn’t. So, in that case for the `set` which is `nil` to change into a wrapped Set containing a value, the function will have to assign to self and that requires *mutating*.

Answer (score 0):

[vacawama and Leo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73179138/12577044) is correct but you want to understand why your code doesn't work. I'll try to explain why does not work as you expected. The function you created "myInsert" defines a Set object, inserts the parameter value and returns the newly created Set object. The problem is you are not actually assigning the created Set object to actual Set variable (which is "self") that you are working on.

```
if let unwrappedSet: Set<String> = self {
    var newSet: Set<String> = unwrappedSet // assigning nil valued "self" to a variable doesn't assign the original variable. Assigning nil to another variable makes that variable again nil. Both are equal (they are nil) but not same variables.
    newSet.insert(value) // inserts value to second Set object not to "self". So still, your actual Set doesn't contains the given value.
    return newSet // returns the value inserted Set object, not "self".
}
else {
    let set: Set<String>? = [value]
    return set
}
```

If we look at myTest() function you can see that your adding operation doesn't work on actual variable.

```
var set: Set<String>? = nil
set.myInsert("Hello") // at this point, myInsert function returns a new Set object with inserted given value. But this operation does not effect the original variable above. That means set variable is still nil
return set // returns nil variable.
```

I hope this helps.