# How can I extend append method for Array in optional in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am working to make this code works for optional array, but Xcode complain about:

> Cannot assign value of type '[Wrapped.Element]' to type 'Wrapped'

Not sure why should be an error?

```
extension Optional where Wrapped: RangeReplaceableCollection, Wrapped.Element: Equatable {

    mutating func customAppend(_ value: Wrapped.Element) {
        if (self != nil) {
            self?.append(value)
        }
        else {
            self = [value] // Cannot assign value of type '[Wrapped.Element]' to type 'Wrapped'
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: The solution is pretty similar to that answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/73179138/2303865

Comment: Note that the `Wrapped.Element`'s constraint to `Equatable` there is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

This will compile:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped: RangeReplaceableCollection, Wrapped.Element: Equatable {
    mutating func customAppend(_ value: Wrapped.Element) {
        if (self != nil) {
            self?.append(value)
        }
        else {
            self = .init([value]) // <--- RangeReplaceableCollection.init(_ elements:)
        }
    }
    
}
```

This works because `RangeReplaceableCollection` declares this init:

```
init<S>(_ elements: S) where S : Sequence, Self.Element == S.Element
```

So that init is available to any conforming type, and gives the appropriate concrete type.

On the other hand, trying to do `self = [value]` *doesn't* work, because that's trying to set self to an `Array`. But since the extension is on `RangeReplaceableCollection`, you can't set `self` to an `Array`, because that's not its type.

Comment: Why not simply `init` if `nil` and then just `append`? `if self == nil { self = .init() }` `self?.append(value)`

Comment: @LeoDabus Sure! That would be equivalent and maybe clearer.

Comment: Your answer is not enough as a correct answer, there is no initialization for `RangeReplaceableCollection` as you commented like "RangeReplaceableCollection.init(_ elements:)" or in explaining, Also there is no need to use `Equatable` protocol as Leo said! Your answer does some issues, also you just used `.init()` which that is not enough, you could say `Wrapped.init([value])` or `Wrapped([value])`

Comment: RangeReplaceableCollection does declare that init, here's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangereplaceablecollection/init(_:)-9zkq6

Comment: Additionally, `.init([value])` and `Wrapped([value])` are equivalent here. This is because of type inference: the compiler knows that `self` is of type `Wrapped`, so it infers that `.init([value])` actually means `Wrapped.init([value])`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct and simplified answer:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped: RangeReplaceableCollection {

    mutating func customAppend(_ value: Wrapped.Element) {
        if (self != nil) {
            self?.append(value)
        }
        else {
            self = Wrapped([value])
        }
    }
    
}
```